# Haskell: quickly track down a type or data constructor definition for an external package

Tags: haskell

When I am studying unfamiliar Haskell code, sometimes I come across type and data constructors that are defined elsewhere. I'll try grepping my code and searching Hoogle, which sometimes leads to a quick explanation, but is oftentimes unfruitful.

For example, I spent an hour trying to identify a reference to a data type called `Object` in the Yesod codebase and finally discovered that it was defined in the Data.Yaml package.

Is there a way to quickly follow a symbolic reference to its definition using GHCi? Perhaps loading the same modules in the interpreter and searching the namespace for the unidentified type constructor or symbolic reference?

Comment: Use `:i Typename` in ghci after loading the file in ghci.

Comment: @Sibi this is precisely what I needed! Thanks. I just tried it out, and I'll be using it all the time. I really need to sit down and read the ghci manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can load the code in ghci, just run `:i symbol` (where symbol can be a type or value), and it will tell you where it is defined, as well as where any class instances are defined.

If you can't load the code in ghci, then you might be able to use [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to look it up.  I recommend installing the hoogle search plugin and giving it a very short keyword like "h".  Then you can just type "h symbol" to get a link to it's documentation (which will also take you to the source).